# Android Manifest application android:name multiples names

Tags: android

I have problem with multiples names in my application manifest :

```
<application
    android:name=".ui.AppController" <!-- volley (json) -->
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" <!--  (index other libraries) -->
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

How I can put multiples names ?

Comment: Multiple Application class is not possible in single application

Comment: I can't execute volley + libraries cammons.org... ? pffff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I can put multiples names ?

You can't. Either:

- Have `.ui.AppController` inherit from `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication`, or
- Follow the instructions in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html) to have `.ui.AppController` use `Multidex.install()`, and do not use `MultiDexApplication` at all

Comment: Thanks Android studio not need execute Multidex.install(), but is recommaned in http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html#dev-build (optimized) I work without Multidex.install() and Works well for now(because I get a problem)

Comment: @xavigonzalez: "not need execute Multidex.install()" -- if you are going to use the `multidex` support library, you need to use `MultiDexApplication` or `Multidex.install()`. If you do not wish to use `MultiDexApplication` or `Multidex.install()`, simply remove the `multidex` support library.

Comment: Thanks again, I remove for now, but in a future I will use Multidex.install, to compile correctly other library "cammons"